# How to get last visible DocumentSnapshot in a combined task for Firestore queries?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am combining two queries to do the "not equals" query for a Firestore collection which isn't possible natively in Firestore so I have to do it locally. I need to get the last visible document of my combined task to use for pagination.

Following is the code that I am writing to get a list of documents from both query results.

```
    Query first = firebaseFirestore
            .collection("jobs")
            .whereGreaterThan("createdBy",currentUser.getEmail())
            .orderBy("createdDate",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .limit(2);
    Query second = firebaseFirestore
            .collection("jobs")
            .whereLessThan("createdBy",currentUser.getEmail())
            .orderBy("createdDate",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .limit(2);

    Task<QuerySnapshot> firstTask = first.get();
    Task<QuerySnapshot> secondTask = second.get();


    final Task<List<QuerySnapshot>> combinedTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(firstTask, secondTask);
    combinedTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<QuerySnapshot>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshots) {
            List<Job> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(QuerySnapshot qs: querySnapshots){
                for(DocumentSnapshot document: qs){
                    Job job = document.toObject(Job.class);
                    list.add(job);
                }
            }

            JobAdapter jobAdapter = new JobAdapter(list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(jobAdapter);

            DocumentSnapshot lastVisible = combinedTask.getResult().get()

        }
    });
```

In the line

```
 DocumentSnapshot lastVisible = combinedTask.getResult().get()
```

I can only either access the documents from my first query or my second query so I am unsure how to get the last visible document, I think the last document would be from my second query logically but I am unsure.

Here is the tutorial I was following to accomplish this:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdgKvLll07s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this, by simply creating the `lastVisible` as a global variable in your class:

```
private DocumentSnapshot lastVisible;
```

And then assignin a value in the for loop:

```
final Task<List<QuerySnapshot>> combinedTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(firstTask, secondTask);
combinedTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<QuerySnapshot>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshots) {
        List<Job> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(QuerySnapshot qs: querySnapshots){
            for(DocumentSnapshot document : qs){
                Job job = document.toObject(Job.class);
                list.add(job);
                lastVisible = qs.getDocuments().get(qs.size() - 1);
            }
        }
        Query nextQuery = firebaseFirestore
                .collection("jobs")
                .whereGreaterThan("createdBy",firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail())
                .orderBy("createdDate",Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
                .startAfter(lastVisible)
                .limit(2);

        //Use the nextQuery
    }
});
```

See the call to `.startAfter(lastVisible)`? So this will work because at the end of the for loop, the `lastVisible` object will always hold the value of the last `DocumentSnapshot` object.

P.S. Thanks for using my tutorial as an example for your Firestore pagination :)